# How to click in a button HTML without class, ID, only tag name input using VBA in MS Access

Tags: html, xml, vba, ms-access, button

I need to click in one button, but I'm struggling to find a way to do it. Because the page is inside my company, it is not accessible to share outside. Here it is a screen capture of it:

[image: Button description]

I updated few fields in the form and the last step is the update. I copy/paste the link in the *onclick* inside my code, but none worked.

I'm using   **Dim getxml As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60** and **getxml = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60** to retrieve the page (not IE).

Thanks for any help. If there is more info needed, let me know.

/sergio

Comment: You cannot click with an xmlhttp request. You can see if there is an xhr generated by performing that click manually that you can emulate instead.

Answer (score 0):

As your page is not accessible for me I can only recommend to use [libEdge](https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge), a Chrome-based browser automation interface to VBA (and other languages).
Here you don't load the page as an object, instead you run javascript directly on it. You can easily achieve what you want with some javascript to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for your reply. I didnt try your solution, and in the end I mapped all the items being sent by POST method and wrote the code to populate the parameters I needed to pass on. One of the param is called Z_ACTION and it is the one simulating the button to be pressed.